# Obtaining a list of donations from a GoFundMe campaign

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

It's a long story as to why I need this information, but I'm looking to obtain a list of the donations on a *GoFundMe* campaign. I would have thought this would have been possible through an API, but much to my distress *GoFundMe* doesn't seem to have an API. This led me down a rabbit hole of web scraping the campaign page.

This gave me some of the information I needed (The total amount of money raised and the goal/target), but for some reason whenever I go to scrape the section at the bottom of the website that contains the list of donations and their comments, or the `/donations` page attached to every campaign, somewhere along the way an element comes out as blank. For the sake of example, with the `/donations` page, this happens as soon as I scrape down to `<div id="portal">`.

This is my scraping code:

```
headers = {'Accept-Language': 'en-UK,en;q=0.5'}
page = get(URL + "/donations", headers=headers)
soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="__next")
results = results.find("div", class_="page-modal-layout_pageModalLayout__O_yxc")
results = soup.find(id="portal")
```

But the results variable after this step is `<div id="portal"></div>`, whereas I was expecting it to contain a whole multitude of different classes, as it does here in the inspect pane on Google Chrome:

[image: Screen Capture of Compressed Google Chrome Inspect]

I've uploaded a screen capture here because it's easier to see the tree of "`div`"s, and I don't fully understand what I'm looking at as I'm not the best at HTML.

My first assumption as to why I can't access this data would be because it's being accessed from some sort of external database, and that database is locked down and requires some sort of authentication that I clearly don't have to access the data. The problem I have with that initial assumption is that I've found something that does almost what I want it to do: On [this](https://blog.streamelements.com/tools-and-tips-for-hosting-a-charity-stream-11788c189a41) blog page they mention an stream overlay called "*GoFundMe* Alerts by LX", which does indeed function, and receives alerts every time a donation goes through, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how they did it given *GoFundMe*'s lack of API.

Digging around in the inspect view for one of these overlays showed me that they were receiving a lot of data about those donations, one of them looks like this:

`{donation_id: 1102799627, amount: 5, is_offline: false, is_anonymous: true, ...}`

This implied to me that there was some sort of API at play, but unfortunately that was where my search was terminated because I couldn't find any further leads. I may be going down completely the wrong path to try to find how to get this information, and basically what I'm asking is: How do I get GoFundMe donations sent to me live? Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @AndrejKesely This should work for any campaign, so I didn't initially provide it in an attempt to keep things simple, but it's here: https://gofund.me/aa0e5374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's comments API you can use, for example:

```py
import requests


comments_url = "https://gateway.gofundme.com/web-gateway/v1/feed/24hr-stream-2024-reformation-fundraising/comments"

params = {"limit": 10, "offset": 0}
data = requests.get(comments_url, params=params).json()

for c in data["references"]["contents"]:
    donation = c.get("donation", {})
    print(c["name"], donation.get("amount", 0))
```

Prints:

```
Andrew Knight A B KNIGHT 5.0
```

You can check this URL in periodic intervals and send an alert on every change.

Comment: You sir, are a life saver. I don't suppose I'm able to get the message associated with those donations as well? Not a problem if not, just interested to see if it's possible because I don't fully understand what you've done here.

Comment: @Lordimass Just put the URL https://gateway.gofundme.com/web-gateway/v1/feed/24hr-stream-2024-reformation-fundraising/comments?limit=10&offset=0 into the browser and you will see there's a comment section too (`c['comment']['comment']`)

Comment: Ah awesome thanks, that makes sense. Thanks for the help!